# LDAP through Ruby or Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-directory, ldap

I've been attempting to hook a Rails application up to ActiveDirectory. I'll be synchronizing data about users between AD and a database, currently MySQL (but may turn into SQL Server or PostgreSQL).

I've checked out activedirectory-ruby, and it looks really buggy (for a 1.0 release!?). It wraps Net::LDAP, so I tried using that instead, but it's really close to the actual syntax of LDAP, and I enjoyed the abstraction of ActiveDirectory-Ruby because of its ActiveRecord-like syntax.

Is there an elegant ORM-type tool for a directory server? Better yet, if there were some kind of scaffolding tool for LDAP (CRUD for users, groups, organizational units, and so on). Then I could quickly integrate that with my existing authentication code though Authlogic, and keep all of the data synchronized.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is sample code I use with the [net-ldap](http://net-ldap.rubyforge.org/) gem to verify user logins from the ActiveDirectory server at my work:

```
require 'net/ldap' # gem install net-ldap

def name_for_login( email, password )
  email = email[/\A\w+/].downcase  # Throw out the domain, if it was there
  email << "@mycompany.com"        # I only check people in my company
  ldap = Net::LDAP.new(
    host: 'ldap.mycompany.com',    # Thankfully this is a standard name
    auth: { method: :simple, email: email, password:password }
  )
  if ldap.bind
    # Yay, the login credentials were valid!
    # Get the user's full name and return it
    ldap.search(
      base:         "OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=mycompany,DC=com",
      filter:       Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "mail", email ),
      attributes:   %w[ displayName ],
      return_result:true
    ).first.displayName.first
  end
end
```

The `first.displayName.first` code at the end looks a little goofy, and so might benefit from some explanation:

- [`Net::LDAP#search`](http://net-ldap.rubyforge.org/Net/LDAP.html#method-i-search) always returns an array of results, even if you end up matching only one entry. The first call to `first` finds the first (and presumably only) entry that matched the email address.
- The [`Net::LDAP::Entry`](http://net-ldap.rubyforge.org/Net/LDAP/Entry.html) returned by the search conveniently lets you access attributes via method name, so `some_entry.displayName` is the same as `some_entry['displayName']`.
- Every attribute in a `Net::LDAP::Entry` is always an array of values, even when only one value is present. Although it might be silly to have a user with multiple "displayName" values, LDAP's generic nature means that it's possible. The final `first` invocation turns the array-of-one-string into just the string for the user's full name.

Comment: Thanks for the late answer. I hardly need this information anymore, but this syntax looks stellar, and MUCH shorter than the way I was attempting to do it. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I had been hitting a wall simply because I wasn't including the @company.com for the user name. Your post got me going in the proper direction.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried looking at these:

http://saush.wordpress.com/2006/07/18/rubyrails-user-authentication-with-microsoft-active-directory/

http://xaop.com/blog/2008/06/17/simple-windows-active-directory-ldap-authentication-with-rails/

Comment: mrT - Many of the links that presumably once worked in your answer are now broken. Could you be persuaded to update them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: new how to authenticate with ldap link: http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/howtoauthenticatewithrubynetldap

Answer (score 4):

This is more anecdotal than a real answer...

I had a similar experience using Samba and OpenLDAP server. I couldn't find a library to really do what I wanted so I rolled my own helper classes.

I used [ldapbrowser](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~gawor/ldap/index.html) to see what fields Samba filled in when I created a user the "official" way and and basically duplicated that.

The only tricky/non-standard LDAP thing was the crazy password encryption we have:

userPass:

```
"{MD5}" + Base64.encode64(Digest::MD5.digest(pass))
```

sambaNTPassword:

```
OpenSSL::Digest::MD4.hexdigest(Iconv.iconv("UCS-2", "UTF-8", pass).join).upcase
```

For the `def authenticate(user, pass)` function I try to get LDAP to bind to the domain using their credentials, if I catch an exception then the login failed, otherwise let them in.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I was looking for a way to generate an nt password hash in ruby :)

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, cannot comment yet...  perhaps someone can relocate this appropriately.

@Phrogz's solution works well, but bind_simple (inside bind) raises an Net::LDAP::LdapError exception due to auth[:username] not being set as shown here:

https://github.com/ruby-ldap/ruby-net-ldap/blob/master/lib/net/ldap.rb

The corrected replaces:

```
auth: { method: :simple, email: email, password:password }
```

with:

```
auth: { method: :simple, username: email, password:password }
```

Comment: Incidentally, you can edit other people's posts -- the edits will go into the Suggested Edits queue, where two people can confirm or deny the edit is a good one. :)

Answer (score 2):

I began using ruby-activedirectory, and even extended it/fixed a few things, hosting judy-activedirectory in Github.

Doing the next iteration, I've discovered ActiveLdap has a much better code base, and I'm seriously contemplating switching to it. Does anyone have personal experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out thoughtbot's ldap-activerecord-gateway? It might be something for you to consider...

http://github.com/thoughtbot/ldap-activerecord-gateway/tree/master

Comment: Hmm. I'm still trying to understand what this could do for us. Essentially, I would start this ldap server when starting the rails application. Then, if there's a way to replicate data between this and the real AD server, do that. Then use my ldap server for data.

Does that make sense?

Comment: this repo is not existent anymore.