# How to test if number of entries returned is 0 using ruby net-ldap

Tags: ruby, ldap

Building on the search example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334519/ldap-through-ruby-or-rails), how would one use the net-ldap Gem to test whether the [`search()`](http://net-ldap.rubyforge.org/Net/LDAP.html#method-i-search) method returns no results, or some results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By how it's used in the other question you linked to, it seems to return an array, so you could just call `empty?` on the result.

There's also this interesting bit of information in the documentation you linked to:

> When :return_result => false, search will return only a Boolean, to
>   indicate whether the operation succeeded.