# Windows Authentication with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, devise, ldap, windows-authentication

I have website running in my intranet, currently all users login to the website using LDAP - they need to write down their username and password.

I know that in ASP.NET, I can have Windows Authentication, which will remove the login process in my intranet.

How can I do this in Ruby on Rails using Nginx? I saw options for using IIS as proxy.. before I will quit and do this, do you have any idea?

Comment: I have never have to use LDAP myself but my first intuition was people surely have already came across this challenge before. Thus, here are the first few results from Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334519/ldap-through-ruby-or-rails, http://wiki.phys.ethz.ch/readme/devise_with_ldap_for_authentication_in_rails_3, http://net-ldap.rubyforge.org/Net/LDAP.html

Answer (score 1):

This is answer for you question: http://wiki.phys.ethz.ch/readme/devise_with_ldap_for_authentication_in_rails_3

Comment: Hi Oleg, What I meant that in Intranet application you can automatically login the username like in ASP.NET Intranet applications. I already use devise with ldap, but I don't the users to sign in.

Comment: the link broken

Answer (score 1):

I havn't tested out this module, but this is what you want:

https://github.com/fintler/nginx-mod-auth-kerb

Kerberos is the way to go with this one, there's also an Apache module out there.

I'm not entirely certain where it would give you the Username - let me know if you find where it gets set