# How to Authenticate a Rails application with Active Directory (via LDAP)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-directory, ldap

I am building a Web Application using Ruby on Rails, i want to build authentication with active directory via LDAP.
And i have no idea how to authenticate with active directory via LDAP.

Can someone provide me how to code it and where we have to put the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334519/ldap-through-ruby-or-rails?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do I have to configure anything else? any additional resources I can find concerning authentication with Active Directory. I am not sure how to fully implement the example you provided. @Unixmonkey

Comment: Not really. It calls a service (LDAP) with credentials, and determines if they are valid or not. The rest of it is up to you (but off-topic for this post). Here's a similar implementation that I used a long time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013354/how-to-ruby-on-rails-authentication-with-ldap/45015896#45015896

Comment: okay thank you, and where we have to put this code ? (location) @Unixmonkey

Comment: It doesn't really matter much, as Rails autoloads just about everything, so classes are available app-wide. `/app/models/ldap.rb` or `app/models/concerns/ldap.rb` seem appropriate to me.

Comment: Thank you, do we have to add some file(or configuration) under /lib or under /config to use LDAP ? @Unixmonkey

Comment: No, not the way that stand-alone class is currently setup.